# How can i sandbox CSS code in iframes page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I block css code in iframe tag with sandbox attribute

code

```
<iframe src="https://test.com/" width="100%" height="100%" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-presentation allow-orientation-lock allow-modals allow-forms"></iframe>
```

Comment: You can't tamper with the contents of an iframe. Just make an ajax call for html and load it into a container on the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the available attributes of `sandbox`, you CAN'T.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox

One option would be to use ajax to fetch the document, parse and remove the css before using the html. Or if the document is in your own control, use ajax to obtain just the html you want.